# WPF ComboBoxItem IsPressed Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have created a ComboBox template to match my application style for which I pretty much set all colors to different values.

I want to have three different state colors for the comboboxitem.

1. normal Item - Background is White
2. MouseHover or Keyboard selection - Background is Dark Blue
3. Is Pressed - Background is Light Blue (you can only see this color, when you press the left mousebutton down, after releasing the mouse button, the popup will close)

The user should see a color feedback, when he presses a comboboxitem

> **Restriction**: I'd rather not use a custom combobox class that supports the `isPressed` event, since I want to keep the usability as high as possible.

My current XAML style

**Templates**

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton.Template" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            CornerRadius="2"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
            Margin="1" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    <Path x:Name="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" 
          Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox.Template" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
          Focusable="False"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBox.Template" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton.Template}"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Focusable="false"
                  ClickMode="Press"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                      Margin="3,3,23,3"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
             Style="{x:Null}"
             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox.Template}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Margin="3,3,23,3"
             Focusable="True"
             Background="Transparent"
             Visibility="Hidden"
             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" 
             Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
    <Popup x:Name="Popup"
           Placement="Bottom"
           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           Focusable="False"
           PopupAnimation="Slide">
      <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
         <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
           <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                       KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
          </ScrollViewer>
      </Grid>
    </Popup>
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
      <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
          <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
          <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItem.Template" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Border x:Name="Border"
          Padding="2"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter />
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Styles**

```xml
<Style x:Key="ComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Template}"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
     </Trigger>
     <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
     </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem.Template}"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Trigger>
    <!-- Trigger for IsPressed somehow? -->
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Most of the code is not neccessary, but I included it, so others can copy paste it to try.

I also tried to edit the ComboBoxItem Template with adding a Button around the `ContentPresenter` but that disabled the selection event (so you couldn't select any item from the comboBox)

Most of the code is from the msdn: [combobox-styles-and-templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates)

Comment: The `Popup` is closed immediately when you select an item so you won't be able to see the highlighting anyway. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: @mm8 the popup is closed after I release the mouse button, not when I press it. Will clarify that

Answer (score 0):

I've overcome this issue by replacing the Border in the template with a PressableBorder control which is a Border with IsPressed property and then using the property in the trigger.

Hint: normally one would also use BoxedBooleans in the dependency property to avoid constant boxing. It's omitted for simplicity.

```
public class PressableBorder : Border
{
    #region public bool IsPressed { get; protected set; } // dp

    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPressedProperty);
        protected set => SetValue(IsPressedPropertyKey, value);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsPressedPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(IsPressed), typeof(bool), typeof(PressableBorder),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPressedProperty =
        IsPressedPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    #endregion

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsPressed = true;

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsPressed = false;

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    }
}
```